# Cookie Banner does not appear with amp

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to make an amp version of my website but have been stuck trying to get my cookie banner to load. I have used the `<amp-script>` tag to reference my external javascript and here is the external javascript

```
const cookieContainer = document.querySelector(".cookie-container");
const cookieButton = document.querySelector(".cookie-btn");

cookieButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  cookieContainer.classList.remove("active");
  localStorage.setItem("cookieBannerDisplayed", "true");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("cookieBannerDisplayed")) {
    cookieContainer.classList.add("active");
  }
}, 2000);
```

also here is the CSS I wrote for it

```
.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);

  transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-container a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-btn {
  background: #e84118;
  border: 0;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  


.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);

  transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-container a {
  color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-btn {
  background: #e84118;
  border: 0;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

but when I load my HTML in my browser the cookie banner does not appear.

Comment: Hi Sandro, welcome to SO! Try to be more specific, are the HTML CSS and JS correctly loaded? do you have any error in the JS console?

Comment: I do not have any errors in the js console.